# What is the role of Pyomo/JuMP/Yalmip in solving optimization model using Python/Julia/Matlab and Gurobi Solver?

Tags: optimization, solver, pyomo, gurobi

I am trying to understand the role of modeling frameworks such as Pyomo for Python, JuMP for Julia, and Yalmip for Matlab in solving the optimization model. I am solving a model with many constraints using Pyomo and Gurobi solver. It takes a long time to output the results of the solved model, even though the actual time taken by the solver (Gurobi) to solve the model is relatively small. I am assuming these modeling frameworks are the bottleneck. Therefore, I wanted to understand why we needed to use modeling frameworks. Also, I got to know that the computation process in these frameworks cannot be parallelized. Does anyone know the role of these frameworks in solving an optimization model?

I looked up online but could not find anything.